# git commit error: version inconsistency between python 2 and python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, git, python-2.7, pre-commit-hook

I am using Python 3.7 for my project. Then when I tried to do

```
edamame$ git commit --amend --no-edit
```

I got the follow error (`git status` works fine though):

```
Your PYTHONPATH points to a site-packages dir for Python 3.x but you are running Python 2.x!
     PYTHONPATH is currently: "/Users/edamame/tools/sim/scripting/:/usr/local/lib/python3.7/:/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/"
     You should `unset PYTHONPATH` to fix this.
```

I tried the below but no luck:

```
edamame$ pip3 install git

Collecting git
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement git (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for git
```

So I have to set the PYTHONPATH each time manually like below, which is very inconvenient. Any advise? Thanks!

```
edamame$ export PYTHONPATH=
```

Comment: `git commit` doesn't normally invoke Python. Do you have any enabled hooks in `.git/hooks`, and if so, are those using Python?

Comment: I have the following things under .git/hooks: commit-msg.sample         post-merge                pre-commit.sample         pre-receive.sample
..                        fsmonitor-watchman.sample post-update.sample        pre-push                  prepare-commit-msg.sample
applypatch-msg.sample     post-checkout             pre-applypatch.sample     pre-push.sample           update.sample
commit-msg                post-commit               pre-commit                pre-rebase.sample    but I am not sure if they use Python ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Bash shell`, you can add `export PYTHONPATH=` to your `~/.bashrc` then reload `~/.bashrc` with the following command:

```sh
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

That way you won't have to enter `export PYTHONPATH=` each time manually.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that either your `pre-commit` or your `post-commit` hook uses Python 2.7.

You should open each of those in an editor and see if they're using Python 2.7 (by looking at the shebang), either a custom version, or one of `/usr/bin/python`, `/usr/bin/python2`, or `/usr/bin/python2.7`. If so, you should convert it to use Python 3 with an appropriate shebang or remove it (simply deleting it is sufficient).

If it came from another project or repository, you could try reinstalling a Python 3 version of that project instead, which would likely install a Python 3 version of your hook.